# Is it possible to solve for $m$ in a linear equation without knowing $b$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Suppose you know certain points on a line say $(5,2)$ up to $(8,10)$ but you don't know exactly where the $y$ intercept would be being somewhere down there at like $-25$ area. How would you solve for $b$ and $m$? Thanks!

Comment: you mean the equation $y=mx+b$?

Comment: holy crap! I figured it out! It appears a 25 year old memory archive is still intact and has been waiting all these years to come to use for me. And to think those high school math class were pointless. B=-23.3. Oh but not for the example numbers I gave but for (7,0) & (10,10). This is for a real estate excel equation. If a motivated seller is willing to finance 100% their property to  me I'll give them 100% the retail value, otherwise if they finance 0%, or I pay all cash I can pay them 70% full market value(minus repairs). I just wanted an equation to come up with the in between's.

Answer (score 3):

You know that $(x,y) = (5,2)$ and $(x,y) = (8,10)$ satisfy the equation $y = mx+b$ where $m$ is the slope of the line and $b$ is the $y$-intercept. This gives you:

$2 = 5m + b$

$10 = 8m + b$

Now, you have two linear equations and two unknowns. Can you solve for $m$ and $b$?

Answer (score 1):

or you use the formula $$m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$$

Answer (score 1):

The equation of a line through a point $(x_1,y_1)$ with slope $m$ has equation
$$
y-y_1=m(x-x_1)
$$
A line passing through two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ has slope
$$
m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}
$$
Thus, the equation of a line passing through two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ has equation
$$
y-y_1=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1)\tag{1}
$$

In your case, we have
\begin{align*}
(x_1,y_1) &= (5,2) & (x_2,y_2) &= (8,10)
\end{align*}
Can you plug these points into the equation (1) to obtain your desired equation?

Answer (score 0):

Two points determine a line. From the two points you can find the slope by computing the ratio of the differences in $y$ coordinates and in $x$ coordinates. Then you can plug the slope and one of the points into the slope-intercept form of the equation and solve for the $y$-intercept.

Answer (score 0):

As the line is passing through the points $(5, 2)$ & $(8, 10)$ hence the equation is given as 
$$y-2=\frac{10-2}{8-5}(x-5)$$ $$y=\frac{8}{3}x-\frac{34}{3}$$ Compare with $y=mx+b$ $$\text{slope}, m=\frac{8}{3}$$$$ \text{y-intercept}, b=-\frac{34}{3}$$